# Is the paint function in java graphics called multiple times when I add a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a chess game in which each tile(class) holds an X and Y position and the board is represented by a two dimensional array of tiles. I have a class called board which extends JComponent and my main function adds the board to a JFrame. Based on what I have read, the paint function is called implicitly(not sure). The problem is that when i tried printing the x and y position of the tiles(being iterated over) it prints all of the x and y positions three times, which led me to believe that paint is being called more than once.

Board class:

```
class Board extends JComponent{
    Tile[][] board1;
    Board(Pieces p,boolean containPiece){   
        //initialize board
        board1 = board; // set attribute

    }
      public void paint(Graphics g){
          for(int i = 0; i < board1.length; i++){
              for(int j = 0; j < board1.length; j++){
                  g.fillRect(board1[j][i].xPosition+130, board1[j][i].yPosition+20,board1[j][i].tileWidth,board1[j][i].tileHeight);
                  System.out.println(j+ " "+ " " + i );
                  if((j+i)%2 == 0){
                      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                  }
                  else{
                      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                  }

              }
            }
          }
      }
```

Main class:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setBounds(350,10,700, 600);
            Knight k = new Knight("Knight","K","white",4,5,3);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new Board(k,true));
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
```

the output is the following(not in same format as code but same content) but repeated twice more:

```
0 0, 1 0, 2 0, 3 0, 4 0, 5 0, 6 0, 7 0,
0 1 ,1 1 ,2 1 ,3 1 ,4 1 ,5 1 ,6 1 ,7 1,
0 2 ,1 2 ,2 2 ,3 2 ,4 2 ,5 2 ,6 2 ,7 2 ,
0 3 ,1 3 ,2 3 ,3 3 ,4 3 ,5 3 ,6 3 ,7 3 ,
0 4 ,1 4 ,2 4 ,3 4 ,4 4 ,5 4 ,6 4 ,7 4,
0 5 ,1 5 ,2 5 ,3 5 ,4 5 ,5 5 ,6 5 ,7 5 ,
0 6 ,1 6 ,2 6 ,3 6 ,4 6 ,5 6 ,6 6 ,7 6 ,
0 7 ,1 7 ,2 7 ,3 7 ,4 7 ,5 7 ,6 7 ,7 7
```

Comment: Won't answer your question but custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` not paint(). Note you should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class and then use the `pack()` method of the frame, not the setBounds() methods. Only your component know the proper size of your grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From The [Oracle Painting in AWT and Swing Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#triggers)

> In a system-triggered painting operation, the system requests a component to render its contents, usually for one of the following reasons:
>
> - The component is first made visible on the screen.
> - The component is resized.
> - The component has damage that needs to be repaired. (For example, something that previously obscured the component has moved, and a previously obscured portion of the component has become exposed).